# how to understand "Estimated droppable tombstones”?

Tags: cassandra

I have output from sstablemetadata for cassandra, i understand this Estimated droppable tombstones is an estimation of tombstones, but what exactly this number mean?

```
[root@cass04 ~]# du -sh /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/* | sort -h | tail -6  
26G /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-9310-Data.db
99G /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-8374-Data.db
113G    /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-8714-Data.db
170G    /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-9063-Data.db
201G    /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-8146-Data.db
271G    /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/Telesto-DeviceImpressions-ka-8084-Data.db
[root@cass04 ~]# du -sh /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto*/* | sort -h | tail -6 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs /usr/local/apache-cassandra/tools/bin/sstablemetadata | grep tombstones^C
[root@cass04 ~]# du -sh /mnt/cassandra/data/Telesto/DeviceImpressions-53cf1590475911e5bad7894bc771451d/* | sort -h | tail -6 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs /usr/local/apache-cassandra/tools/bin/sstablemetadata | grep tombstones
Estimated droppable tombstones: 6.137201062686473E-5
Estimated droppable tombstones: 1.1680085943591365E-4
Estimated droppable tombstones: 6.626254059536159E-5
Estimated droppable tombstones: 5.116100385316167E-5
Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.8704887039387946
Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.10260068095210549
```

Answer (score 3):

Its an approximate ratio from the number of tombstones that are droppable (past gc grace) to the number of columns.

In example, if theres 10 columns. 8 of which are tombstones past the seven day gc grace period, its 8/10 or `0.8`.

If this is above the `tombstone_threshold` (0.2 default, compaction strategy option) its possible that it will get a single sstable compaction to clear out the tombstones.

There are scenarios where it will still not happen. those can be tuned with other options `tombstone_compaction_interval`, `unchecked_tombstone_compaction`

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html

Comment: What would a > 1 ratio mean than? I sometimes see 1.25, 2.0, etc.

Comment: you have more tombstones then columns.